# Redirecting Rails form_tag to a modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

In my rails app I have a form_tag which I want to be redirected to a modal when submitted. I have the following for the form_tag but the problem is the modal pops-up when i click on the fields of the form.

```
<%= form_tag generate_report_path, 
      {method: :get, remote: true, 
         'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} do %>
```

my geneate_report method

```
def generate_report
  ####code to get relevant student_ids
  @students = Student.where(id: @student_ids)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render 'reports/show_report'}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the modal to pop up when the submit button is pressed simply move

```
'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'
```

to your button_tag.

I think you might actually want to have the modal open when the user receives a response from the server after submitting the form. If so, simply manually open the modal in your create.js.erb file (the view being rendered by the remote form submit).

```
$('#modal-window').modal('show');
```

Comment: Yes, it is the latter which I want. But the controller is not attached to any model. It is a report generating controller.  So I have a 'reports' controller and 'generate_report' method. So, when the form_tag above is submitted it goes to the generate_report method. at the views, I have '_show_report.html.erb' partial and 'show_report.js.erb'. in my generate_report method I have        respond_to do |format|
   format.js {render 'reports/show_report'}    end                                                                 The error message I get is ActionController::UnknownFormat

Comment: Can you post your generate_report method from the reports controller?

Comment: Are you remembering to use escape_javascript when rendering your partial in the show_report.js.erb file?

Comment: yes, this is what I have there   $("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'reports/show_report') %>")

Comment: This should be: `$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'reports/show_report')) %>")`

Comment: Can you post the entire stack dump? This all looks right to me. I'm not sure what is missing at this point.

Comment: Started GET "/generate_report?locale=en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-04 12:07:12 +0300
Processing by ReportsController#generate_report as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
  Setting Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings" WHERE "settings"."param" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["param", "per_page"]]
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 2ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:82:in `generate_report'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66195/discussion-between-tiamon-and-ken-stipek).

Comment: I'm actually just headed to bed, but it looks like your server is trying to process this as HTML and not JS, from what you posted `Processing by ReportsController#generate_report as HTML` Good luck :)

Comment: Before you go, Is this line correct? <%= form_tag generate_report_path(:remote => true, :method => :get) do %>